# Find degressive cost function that goes through two points

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function

I need to find the root function (degressive cost function) that goes through the points 
$$
 P_{1} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  50 \\ 79
\end{array} \right], 
\qquad
 P_{2} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  5000 \\ 3200
\end{array} \right]
$$
where the function is (I believe) something like
$$
 f(x) = \frac{x^{c}}{a}
$$

Does anyone know how to find the function? Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange, M.SE! This quick tutorial will help you in learning MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Please make questions as clear and succinct as practical. For example, what are your parameters $a$ and $c$? Are they free; are the specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$ (where $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ are known), and that $f(x)=\frac{x^c}{a}$.  To determine $c$ and $a$, observe that 
$$\frac{y_2}{y_1}=\frac{f(x_2)}{f(x_1)}=\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^c.$$
Taking the natural logarithm and dividing yields 
$$c=\frac{\log y_2-\log y_1}{\log x_2-\log x_1}.$$
So now $c$ is known, and to find $a$ just rearrange the definition of $f$ to isolate it:
$$a=\frac{x_1^c}{f(x_1)}=\frac{x_1^c}{y_1}.$$

Comment: Absolutely brilliant (from my humble point of view), thank you!

Comment: @PhiAl You're welcome.  Glad to help!